# How to install google chrome?

Tags: kali-linux

I am solving a problem in Kali Linux when I was installed the google chrome package and I wanted to install but it shows like this:

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

> Reading package lists... Done

> Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Note, selecting 'google-chrome-stable' instead of './google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'                                                                                                                                               
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have                                                                                                                                                                          
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable                                                                                                                                                                         
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created                                                                                                                                                                         
or been moved out of Incoming.                                                                                                                                                                                                             
The following information may help to resolve the situation:                                                                                                                                                                               
> 
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:                                                                                                                                                                                            
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installable                                                                                                                                                            
                        Recommends: libu2f-udev but it is not installable                                                                                                                                                                  
                        Recommends: libvulkan1 but it is not installable                                                                                                                                                                   
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **gdebi** instead of **apt**.

`sudo gdebi google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Read carefully an extract from `man gdebi` DESCRIPTION section:

> ```
>    gdebi  lets  you  install local deb packages resolving and installing
>    its dependencies. apt does the same, but only for remote (http,  ftp)
>    located packages. It can also resolve build-depends of debian/control
>    files.
> ```

Comment: but it says can't locate the package

Comment: @ChongKarHee By "can't locate the package" you mean those 3 packages: xdg-utils, libu2f-udev, libvulkan1? Have you tried to install any of them manually prior chrome installation? By the way, in case of libu2f-udev as I remember you should try install  libu2f-host.

Comment: @ChongKarHee I also checked *libvulkan1* on [pkg.kali.org](https://pkg.kali.org/) and it seems you could try install *vulkan-loader* instead.

Comment: @ChongKarHee Just only for make it sure: type `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and show us what is the ouptut of `grep --invert-match '#' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: ok I will try your ways